# Invoke timer from background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

What I want to do. I want to SomeMethod will be called periodically. Therefore, I want to timer will be started from backgroung thread after body of background thread method is passed. `_timer.Start()` was invoked, but TickHandler doesn't;

code:

```
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

class TestTimer
    {
        private Timer _timer;
        private Thread _thread;

        public TestTimer()
        {
            // create and initializing timer. but not started!
            _timer = new Timer();
            _timer.Tick += TickHandler;
            _timer.Interval = 60000; // 1 minute

            // create and start new thread
            _thread = new Thread(SomeMethod);
            _thread.Start();
        }

        private void TickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // stop timer
            _timer.stop();

            //some handling

            // run background thread again
            _thread = new Thread(SomeMethod);
            _thread.Start();
        }   

        private void SomeMethod()
        {
            // some operations

            // start timer!
            TimerStart();
        }

        private void TimerStart()
        {
            _timer.Start();
        } 
    }
```

By monkey method I found if add Delegate like this

```
internal delegate void TimerDelegate();
```

And replace string

```
TimerStart();
```

with

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new TimerDelegate(TimerStart), null);
```

all works fine. Somebody can explain me what is the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got things mixed up a bit.

If you want a timer that *fires* on a **background thread**, you don't have to create a thread to start it (it doesn't matter which thread calls the `Start` method). Just use `System.Timers.Timer`, and each `Elapsed` event will occur on a thread-pool thread.

If you want a timer that *fires* on the **UI thread**, since it looks like you're using WPF, you should use `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`, and not the Windows Forms timer you've been using. You should *create* the timer (i.e. call `new`) on a particular UI thread, and every `Tick` event will occur on that thread. Again, it doesn't matter from which thread you call `Start`.

Here's an explanation of what's happening in your code: You're starting a Windows Forms timer on a non-UI thread. This kind of timer requires a message pump to be running on that thread so it can receive messages. Because it's a non-UI thread, there's no message pump. When you used the `Dispatcher.Invoke` method, you marshaled the creation of the timer back to the application's main UI thread, which made it work. But it is all quite redundant. If you want to keep the code as is, just replace the timer with a `DispatcherTimer`, and then you'll be able to remove the `Invoke` call.

Alternatively, if you're using .NET 4.5 you could use await/async to make this all much easier (be sure to call `SomeMethod` from the UI thread):

```
async Task SomeMethod(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => DoAsyncStuff(), ct);

        DoUIStuff();

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), ct);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want a timer that fires on the UI thread, but I forced started it from background thread. I don't create background thread to start timer :), I use background thread to do some operations, and after these operations I want restart timer. So, actually, I need start timer from UI thread, but I dunno when background thread finished work. Therefore I try to start timer from background thread. Anyway thx, I understand you, almost... I think I need read more about threading.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) can explain it for you:

> Note The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is
>   limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a
>   multithreaded timer with greater accuracy, use the Timer class in the
>   System.Timers namespace.